# How bad would it be to dump nuclear waste into the atmosphere?

Tags: nuclear-engineering, climate-science

Before I say any further, this is just a *thought experiment*, it's a crazy idea and I'm not suggesting otherwise!

A key pro/anti nuclear argument goes like so: nuclear waste storage is hard, but on the flipside, coal-fired powerplants get to dump their waste (CO2, soot and all the chemicals) direct into the atmosphere. Nuclear waste, meanwhile, is stored during the lifetime of a plant, and then disposed (or not) in one go, as a then-bulk object. Nuclear proponents also make the point that the worldwide volume of nuclear waste is actually surprisingly small - some variation of "5 storey building the size of a football pitch" for all waste produced to date etc. The equivalent for CO2 - carbon capture and storage - seems elusive and impractical for now, precisely because the waste is thought to be hazardous and hard to keep safe, just like nuclear waste, so instead it gets a free pass to dump its waste into the atmosphere.

So there goes: compared to a coal plant dumping its waste into the atmosphere, how bad would it be if a nuclear plant did the same with its waste, in real time - up a chimney and into the wind? How would just the sheer volume of waste compare against the waste from a coal powerplant? How toxic / radioactive / lethal would it be after dispersing around some area, in particular vs. the soot, sulphides and other coal waste? Or, if we took all nuclear waste from civilian applications, and dispersed it evenly around the world, would it still be bad? How bad is it if we include the global warming effect of the CO2 emitted by a coal plant, vs. the toxicity of nuclear waste?

Nuclear disasters are of course bad, and lead to (debated) releases of toxic materials, but that is different I guess; these are bulk releases of both nuclear waste and fuel still being used, presumably much larger than the hypothesised real-time dumping of *just* the waste material.

I don't even know where to start, and it seems like a nice point of comparison of toxicity of the two sorts of energy sources.

Comment: Hi! So basically you ask whether the total amount (say per year) of freely exhausted waste materials of nuclear power plants compares with the total amount of waste of fossil-based plants, regarding the toxicity of the waste materials that get spread around the world? How will the change in temperature, due to fossil-plants waste gasses, be toxic? What are the mechanisms? The waste that was freed into the atmosphere after Chernobyl did indeed contain not-used material, but the waste was pretty deadly too, as is the fallout of an atomic fission bomb, in which unused material can be found too.

Comment: https://www.veritasium.com/videos/2020/9/16/the-nuclear-fallout-they-kept-secret

Comment: Very bad. At least compared with the alternatives of storeing them at least stationary for a while. There are (no clear boundaries) three kind of waste materials: short decaying (days or weeks), long decaying (thousands of years) and nasty stuff decaying in a few decades. Short decaying pose only a limited threat, if they are not released. Long decaying materials won't release much radioactivity and thus are somehow  controllable. The really nasty stuff is in the middle, decaying fast enough to produce noxious radiation, but tough enough to keep that for centuries.

Comment: Carbon dioxide is "only" a green house gas, increasing the global temperature (if not trapped by plants, for example), whereas radioactive materials (like strontium or iodine) may accumulate in our bodies, doing more harm as if simply distributed at random in our environment.

Answer (score 1):

The stuff that makes nuclear waste radioactive is metallic or ceramic (and is often very chemically reactive). To disperse it in the atmosphere and then rely on dilution to spread it out to nonlethal levels, you'd need some way to prevent it from settling down to earth again by gravity as dust- something we call *radioactive fallout*.

Even if you use an atomic bomb blast or an intense fire to tear the radioactive material into the smallest possible pieces, it will still settle out by gravity and wind will then form it into a plume which creates a radioactive "footprint" on the ground extending for thousands of kilometers away from the blast or burn site- with deadly health effects that persist for years afterwards.

Comment: You could give the real time experiment of Chernobyl  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster

Comment: Xenon isn't metallic nor ceramic. Iodine isn't either. I downvoted.

Comment: @GyroGearloose, for the purposes of storage and disposal, radioactive waste is solid or liquid, and the stuff from which the plant equipment is manufactured is also solid.

Comment: So the question is if the original question is about *fresh* products or *pre-processed* products.

Comment: @annav presumably the release from Chernobyl, as a one-off, was much larger than if it was an on-going, continuous release?

Comment: The effect of the fallout is still there, over a huge area. Radioctivity from  fission products lasts a long time , and affects orgaisms even in  small doses. It could not be "released" to the environment in any harmless way.